# Data format modified when passed from client to server, using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I’m having some trouble when sending my data to the server, with Node.js. I’m pretty sure there are other topics about that same issue around, but I don’t really know what to search for to find it…

My app is very rough:

- 1 html file with a form in it
- 1 global.js, sending data to my server when form is sent
- 1 data.js on the server side, dealing with queries sent by global.js

When I pass my data from the client to the server via $.ajax POST and retrieve it with req.body, the data format is messed up :

**Here is what I send:**

```
newData = { ‘body ‘ : [ { ‘key_1’ : ’stuff’ , ‘key_2’ : ’stuff’ } ] }
```

**And what I get:**

```
req.body == { ‘body[0][key_1]’ : ‘stuff’ , ‘body[0][key_2]’ : ‘stuff’  }
```

---

The full code of my app below:

**global.js:**

```
function sendStuff(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newData = {'body' : ''};
    var items = [{'key_1' : 'stuff', 'key_2' : 'stuff', 'key_3' : 'stuff'}];
    newData.body = items;

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        data        : newData,
        url         : '/data/adddata',
        dataType    : 'JSON'
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (response.msg === '') {
            console.log('Everything ok');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error:' + response.msg);
        }
    });
}
```

**And on the server side, data.js:**

```
router.post('/adddata', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('data');
    console.log(req.body);

    collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

---

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help,

Maxime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a formatting issue...the data is formatted by the ajax call since you are passing an object instead of a JSON string. Try passing `JSON.stringify(newData)` to jquery ajax.

Comment: Well, not sure about this, here is what console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)) gives : 

`{"body[0][type]":"text","body[0][key]":"bhjnk","body[0][value]":"hbjn"}`

Plus, when I retrieve this data from my database, it looks like this : http://grab.by/KXVs

If i store my newData directly in the mongo shell, I get it well formatted : http://grab.by/KXVE

Comment: ok, it means that the data is formatted by jquery ajax. See my edited answer.

Comment: Tried that before... When i send JSON.stringify(newData), here's what it looks like on the client side : `{"body":[{"type":"stuff","key":"jhbkn","value":"jbhkn"}]}` (looks ok), and what I get on the server side : `{ '{"body":[{"type":"stuff","key":"jhbkn","value":"jbhkn"}]}': '' }`. When I try to JSON.parse(req.body), the client gives me an error 500 when data is sent : http://grab.by/KYNu. I'm depressed.

Comment: `JSON.parse` gives you an error because you need to pass a string, and `req.body` is an object.

Comment: Well if I send my stringified data, shouldn't req.body be a string ? I continue searching for the problem, I'll let you know when I find it : )

Comment: ... And then I found it. Just added `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in my ajax request, and everything works... Damn. Thanks for your help anyway!